# MySQL database import silently failing?

Tags: mysql

New to MySQL user so pardon the relative beginner question. I've been searching for an answer to this for the past few hours but just can't figure it out!

I'm trying to import a backup of a wordpress database to a new GCP instance with mySQL. I've copied the *.sql* file to the server & I've typed the import command as follows:

```
mysql - u root -p databasename < databasefile.sql
```

The problem however is that SQL returns no message at all, leaving me to believe the command failed. When I load up Mysql through SSH and try to run `SELECT * FROM databasename;` I'm greeted with.... `Empty set (0.00 sec)`

My questions are...

1. Does the "Empty set" return mean that the database is not importing correctly?
2. Should MySQL return something if the database import was successful?
3. ... Why is SQL not importing my database?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you open the .sql and took a look at it? Can you determine if they're good sql statements or would you integrate your question with the sql file so we might help you solve this arcane.

Comment: Can you recommend a reader to open the file with? I'm on Mac. I did verify the file size is the same on my computer and on the server.

Comment: Use built in graphical text editor. TextEdit I guess..

Comment: Ok - I used "sudo nano" and opened the file in the SSH window. It looks non-corrupted to me. Anything specifically I should be looking for?

Comment: Running a `SELECT` against a database isn't going to be productive. You need to run it against a *table*. Try `use databasename` then `SELECT * from wp_users`.

Comment: Even with his wrong query I assume the restore failed otherwise the site would work and he won't be posting this. :)

Comment: Actually @EEAA seems to have been correct. When I run select wp_users I get the table of wordpress users. So now I'm thinking that the database import has infact been successful the whole time. Now I'm trying to figure out why my wordpress deployment isn't working. I'm currently getting the "Error establishing database connection" on the front page, but when I navigate to /wp-admin/ I see the "Can’t select database" page. Hmmmmm.

Comment: @Marco see above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set `slow_query_log = 1` (if >=5.6.1) or `log_slow_queries = 1`(if <5.6.1) and `slow_query_log_file = /path/to/logfile` and `long_query_time = 0` in my.cnf, then restart mysql restore db again and have a look at the logfile. I won't keep it on on production envs, such a logging is a performance killer and may result in bad things if you are on heavy load. It may also get quickly very big as "long_query_time 0" results in logging everything, so "/path/to" should have plenty of free space.

**This way you will log all server activity and you'll find what's going on with this restore query**.

Disable such options as soon as you can.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! So I went through these steps... and after running the import again nothing appears in the log file. Also just to give more context - I *believe* the import is silently failing because as soon as I hit return on the import, it brings me to the next line with less than a second of wait time.

Comment: What if you mysql -uroot -p and then show databases?

Comment: It shows the database that I've imported.

Comment: So, you'd better move to Wordpress forum? :)

Comment: Yup - marked this as resolved. Thank you for the help @marco.